# Storyboard won't update in simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, ios-simulator

I have a working app in `Xcode`, however when I try to build and run it the simulator displays an older version of the storyboard I was working on. I had changed some of the design on the storyboard but this does not reflect in the simulator, nothing is updated.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Same thing happening with me in Xcode 6.3.1.

Answer (score 22):

1. Delete the App on the simulator.
2. Clean
3. List item
4. Build & Run

Use `NSLog(@"")` in your controller to check code execution.

Comment: It's now paused with Thread 1:Program received signal: "SIGBART". :S

Comment: Check the name of the storyboard in the info.plist - it should be [name of storyboard] with no file extension

Comment: Just tried that and its named as it should be, if it helps its paused on the line : return UIApplicationMain argc, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));

Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: What does the stack trace say? Sometimes there's some useful information there.  Also, check the class of all the objects in the storyboard, make sure there are no references to classes that you've removed from the project.

Comment: You got the SIGBART because you deleted the app while it was still running in xcode. It's not a real problem. It sounds to me it that T0m_Twt is right just clean and run.

Comment: I tried cleaning, deleting and clearing derived data to no avail. See my solution below.

Comment: This helped, thank you. Though there are better ways to debug than `NSLog`.

Comment: Clean... GAAAAAAAAH! Thx for this!

Answer (score 13):

I just spent at least 6 hours on this. I have a solution, but I also submitted a technical support ticket to apple to try to get more info on the cause and proper solution.

**Simply remove the references to your storyboard files and add them back in the same file group.**

This seems to include the storyboard files back into the app bundle generated during build(which can be seen in the

```
DerivedData/APPNAME/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimultator/APPNAME.app
```

From here I can see my changes reflected from the storyboards as expected.

PS - Are you using localization at all? I was.

Comment: Thanks, wasted 2 hours on that, you probably saved me a couple others... 
I was also using localization.

Comment: I had similar issue and was also using localisation. Deleted app in simulator and ran app again from XCode and all good now.

Comment: thanks very much, I had the same problem with localization!

Answer (score 6):

I lost 2 hours to this.

Solution was braindead simple: delete app, **turn OFF** the iPhone 5S (iOS 7.1.1), and turn it bavk on.

Comment: +1 Had the same los of time! First thought I did something wrong with the constraints. Found out you have to delete it on simulator too! If you create your storyboard by copy/pasting it from another layout it doesn't recognize the old app anymore to be replaced on your simulator or device and just launches it again with the old layout.

Answer (score 3):

When you turn on localization, 
xcode moves storyboard file in localization folder (ex. **Base.lproj/name.storyboard**). When you build and run project on simulator, xcode copy name.storyboard into **"derivedData"/Base.lproj/name.storyboard**, but previous, created before localization **"derivedData"/name.storyboard** still exists. In this case simulator uses the file which can be found easier, i.e simulator uses old file **"derivedData"/name.storyboard** to operate.

**Solution:** Just rename the storyboard file, in navigator and in targets/general.

Answer (score 1):

This error happened to me for the first time when I had multiple copies of a project on my computer. For whatever reason, the fact that there were multiple copies were making it look as if the storyboard had not been updated between copies and in some cases the code was not updated. I thought I had forgotten to throw the right copy on my flash drive before going home, but it turned out it's an XCode error.

Delete any multiple copies using the same name, restart XCode and open your most recent copy. Extremely bizarre, but I will probably use BitBucket or GitHub from now on instead of throwing it on a flash drive.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting

> ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/derivedData/

worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I just have the same problem after localizationMy solution is clicking Product, Clean build folder. Then it will be fine

Answer (score 0):

The storyboard on the simulator was what it should have been.  The storyboard on the device would not update.  I had to delete the application from the iPhone and then re-run it on the device in order to get the Storyboard to update on the device.  Fortunately for me it was only test data, but I was using Auto-Layout on one view and went back to manual.  I think that's what caused the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I find that removing and adding storyboard file back doesn't work in my case, also it has side effects like it will automatically add a main nib entry into App's plist file (which subsequently makes the App fails to launch in iPhone simulator).

I don't want to try to delete the application from the simulator since I have many files under the Document directory of the App.

At last I find another way that works well: simply delete the "/Users/$username/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/$app/$yourapp.app" file. The files under Documents directory are untouched.

(I have localized my storyboard as well.)

Answer (score 0):

I found this same thing happened with Xcode 6.1.1 if I happened to have copied a project; the new project run in the simulator was actually still reflecting the *old, original* project.

In my case the problem was with how the default area was set up for derived data (essentially the location where the binary files go for a build). Mine was set to legacy and the simulator was using the wrong project, even after a clean. The solution was to go to *Preferences*->*Locations*, press *Advanced*, and change the location from *Legacy* to *Unique*.

Answer (score 0):

I get this too when using localized storyboards - **Run** in Xcode just refuses to install the latest version of the compiled storyboard. I think it is something to do with the way **Run** copies changed resources across to the device - it does it differently than other forms of on device app installation.

The quickest way to get past this **without deleting the app and losing any data** is to:

- Generate an **Archive** build in Xcode
- Export this for **Adhoc** deployment
- Double-click on the generated **IPA** to add it to iTunes
- From the device page in iTunes force an **update** to that app

In order for iTunes to see that you have a new version your app **build number** will need to be incremented (if you don't do that already), before generating the archive.

I find this method means you don't have to delete an app off the device, you're just forcing it to install the entire install package rather than a diff which is what I think **Run** is doing.

I'm not sure what causes this, if it is a localized resources bug or what, but this is still a problem in Xcode 7 for me.