# Storyboard changes not updating in simulator/iphone

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I have a wierd issue were changes I make on the storyboard are not reflected on the simulator or device. This only occurs when I update the storyboard to xcode5. When reverted back to xcode 4 the storyboard works fine.

I have tried clean and deleting the app but nothing works. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

I have tried this :[Storyboard won't update in simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648871/storyboard-wont-update-in-simulator) but I am not sure how to get to `DerivedData/APPNAME/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimultator/APPNAME.app`

Comment: what changes are you talking about. Are you talking about label positions and so on?

Comment: yeah positioning of the labels and images

Comment: with xcode 5 you need to get the constraints set right. Go in Stroryboard, mark your view controller and then you need to go to the `Edit` menue and Clear All Constraints. Afterwards go back to `Edit` and use the option to Add Missing Constraints. this should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 5 changed the control over constraints. This will often lead to mistakes in the beginning. Use the Resolve Auto Layout Issues button to fix your mistakes.

[image: Xcode 5 Resolve Autolayout Issues]

Go to storyboard and look for the menu bar to find the Resolve Auto Layout Issues button.
There you can update constraints, add missing constraints, reset to suggested constraints, or clear all constraints.