# performSegueWithIdentifier Not Initiating a Segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

My implementation of performSegueWithIdentifier method is not initating a segue.

I have tried debugging by placing print statements before and after the method: it prints before, but not after, which obviously indicates that the method is not working, right?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{

    var signupActive = true

    @IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!

    var errorMessage = "Please try again later"

    func displayAlert(title: String, message: String) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction((UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        })))

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    @IBAction func signUp(sender: AnyObject) {

        if username.text == "" || password.text == "" {

            displayAlert("Error in form", message: "Please enter a username and password")

        } else {

            UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()

            var errorMessage = "Please try again later"

            if signupActive == true {

                var user = PFUser()
                user.username = username.text
                user.password = password.text
                user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in

                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

                    if error == nil {

                        // Right here and below as well

                        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login", sender: self)


                    } else {

                        if let errorString = error!.userInfo["error"] as? String {

                            errorMessage = errorString

                        }

                        self.displayAlert("Failed signup", message: errorMessage)

                    }
                })

            } else {

                PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username.text!, password: password.text!, block: { (user, error) -> Void in

                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

                    if user != nil {

                        // Here too

                        print("kay")
                        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login", sender: self)
                        print("yay")


                    } else {

                        if let errorString = error!.userInfo["error"] as? String {

                            errorMessage = errorString
                        }

                        self.displayAlert("Failed login", message: errorMessage)

                    }

                })
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Run a debug build of your program in Xcode and watch the debugging console. My guess is that that call is throwing an exception which is causing your function to terminate.

Comment: @DuncanC how do you do that ? That's what i've been looking for

Comment: From the view menu, select "Debug Area>Activate Console". Then look in the very lower right corner of your project window for 2 little blue boxes. Make sure they are both blue, and move the divider between the 2 parts of the debug console about half way between the 2 sections. Then run your program and trigger the code in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to execute the segue on the main thread as currently you are executing the segue within a block.

To execute your segue on the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: damn you were 30 seconds to fast for me ;)

Comment: Is this new to iOS 9?

Comment: Good catch. I missed that. To the OP, you are using a parse function called `PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground`. That method name tells you that it does it's thing in the background. You have never been able to make UI changes in the background, under any version of iOS.

Comment: To the OP, if you are asking if `dispatch_async` is new to iOS 9, no. It was added in iOS 4 if memory serves.

Comment: Now  I'm getting `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: xxxxxxxxx>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'UINavigationController-xxx-xx-xxx''`

Comment: That is a separate issue, you can check out this post for reference on how to resolve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25434755/storyboard-exception-storyboard-doesnt-contain-a-view-controller-with-identif

Comment: @chrissukhram uninstalled my app and rebuilt, problem persists

Comment: Hmm you may need to open another question around this issue, are both of your views embedded in a navigation controller?

Comment: I have almost exactly the same code (We're both following the same iOS dev course :P) and my code currently works without using "dispatch_async..." - Should i start using this in my code, what are the benefits/cons of doing/not doing it. - Thanks Kitson