# App Crash "Storyboard doesn't contain a view controller with identifier" on uibutton click

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationcontroller

App crashed with following log:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier
>   'CheckController'

My Code is:

```
-(IBAction)ClkAddToCart:(id)sender
{
    checkViewController *Obj = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CheckController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:Obj animated:YES];
}
```

In other pages it's working but not in this controller.

I have already set the Identifier in my storyboard as shown below:

[image]

Comment: You might be taking the wrong storyboard file.

Comment: Where is the button located ? In same storyboard ?

Comment: @Soberman i have checked, its one and only "Main" in info.plist

Comment: @MidhunMP  Yes, in other controller button located from that to i am navigating to check controller

Comment: Actually, if i am set any new navigation for push then same problem occur on all button clicks, and some is working yet, i have did before tomorrow. not getting why...!! :(

Comment: i have tryed segue also same error getting segue with identifier not found

Comment: is there any thing that prevent the storybord write access like not able to set identifier ?

Comment: @JigneshKanani post source code

Comment: Sorry but its big project what do u want more ?

Comment: @JigneshKanani - Can you make sure that there is no whitespace in storyboard id for this controller. Something like `CheckController `

Comment: @Gandalf i have checked there is no white space

Comment: Hello All, I have put the above code where navigation is working yet, but above code not work there also. plz think diff may be related storybord write access...! its big problem for me.

Comment: Yup..., Thanks to all for your valuable time. Finally fixed the problem by clean app, remove all app from simulator and Also make check mark to target membership. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25434755/storyboard-exception-storyboard-doesnt-contain-a-view-controller-with-identif   Thanks a lot... :)

Answer (score 2):

I encounter same problem when I do a work using storyboard to construct the UI. I tried to use code, but not work. Now I find a solution that works and it's very easy. That is you just clean your project.   On Menu,  Product =>Clean. Please have a try on your project.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I think you should check self.storyboard instance to ensure that you are using the right one.
Secondly, an alternative solution is you can create your own storyboard instance and init CheckViewController with its id.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"storyboardName" bundle:nil];
CheckViewController *checkViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CheckController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:checkViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: let me try and i will let u know