# Ui element dissappers in xcode 6

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, ios8, xcode6

I am trying to put 3 uiimageview like below image but one of them is always missing. 
I added constraints but nothing changed.
When it disappears I am not able to get it back to visible.

[image: XCODE6]
[image]

Here I add one more image to make the problem clear.
 [image]

Comment: What are the constraints for the different image views?

Comment: just the missing one has constraints.

Comment: What are the errors that are shown if you click on the yellow triangle in the top right?

Comment: it is about unused variable, not related with the problem.

Comment: Hm.. I can't reproduce this at all, even with the exact same constraints. If you delete the image view and insert a new one, does the same thing happen?

Comment: yes like last image I add to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that my story board won't update in simulator. 
When I delete the app and clean / rebuild solution it worked as expected.

The steps I followed :

1)Delete the App on the simulator.
2)Clean
3)Build & Run

Here is the link 
[Storyboard won't update in simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648871/storyboard-wont-update-in-simulator)