# Storyboard changes not updating in iphone but work on simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, storyboard, uistoryboard

I change storyboard and add some views or changing background color when i run the project my changes doesn't submit and show in iphone 
I try different way such as clean and re build project Or restart iphone and run again doesn't helpful.
My xcode version is 11.0 and iphone 7 ios 13 
In simulator work properly But in real iphone doesn't work 
also check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648871/storyboard-wont-update-in-simulator/14648953#14648953)

i try clean project and rebuild again and run project and restart iphone and run again and delete Project in DerivedData folder
The only way to run project with changes is to delete project in iphone and run again

Comment: please post what did you try so far.

Comment: Thanks for considering the suggestion, You are new to SO, try following the best practices on how to ask a good question, See more in StackOverflow code of conduct.